# Pandas: cumsum by group across time, resampled to entire dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cumsum

I have a time series data frame. I'm interested in plotting the cumulative sums across time, by groups of [column1, column2]. So far I can only plot the cumulative sum at the points where the group combination existed. What I want is the cumulative sum for each group at every single timestamp in the original data frame, so I can easily plot the total cumulative sum on the same plot as the group cumulative sums.

[EDIT] I got it working by doing this, for each group I'm interested in:

```
values = np.where((df.column1==someVal) & (df.column2==someVal), df.column3, 0).cumsum()
plt.plot(df.timestamp, values)
```

Comment: Sounds like you first want to resample your groups such that a value is available for each timestamp for each group (e.g. forward fill the values). Then you should be able to easily calculate the cumulative sums you are after.

Comment: A minimal code example of the problem you are trying to solve would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
values = np.where((df.column1==someVal) & (df.column2==someVal), df.column3, 0).cumsum()
plt.plot(df.timestamp, values)
```